# Scaling edge from multiple object with local transform is not working as expected

Tags: edges

When I try to scale two edge of two cubes simultaneously in edit mode with local transformation orientation, the scaling center seems off.

Here is a gif demonstrating the problem, [image]

I expect the scaling of each edge to happen from the center of each cube because I've chosen local transform, but the scaling is happening as if the location of the two cubes matter or as if I have global transform selected.

Is this a bug? I have the same problem with rotation.

Comment: why would it happen from the center of each cube? it happens from what you've chosen in the Pivot Point dropdown menu

Comment: I see. Changing the pivot point to individual origin solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: except it will scale from the individual origin (middle) of the selected edges, not the origin of the object, to do this you should rather put your 3D cursor on the object origin and choose 3D cursor as pivot point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing several things:

- *Transformation Orientation* will determine what are the directions displayed by the gizmo in the 3D view, and therefore the directions you'll use: are they relative to the *Global*, *Local* or custom axis, etc... It has nothing to do with the center of the scale or rotation operations you are going to do.
- On the contrary, the *Pivot Point* will determine what will be the center of your operation when you'll scale or rotate.
- In *Object* mode the object origin will be taken into account if for example you scale an object with *Pivot Point* > *Median Point* selected. If you choose *Pivot Point* > *3D Cursor*, it won't, only the 3D cursor will be taken into account.
- In *Edit* mode, the object origin will never be taken into account, if you want this point to be taken into account, put your 3D cursor on it and choose *3D Cursor* as pivot point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can chose Individual Origins and those edge can be scale by them self location.
[image]